# Rails 3- Render partial on an ajax call within a popup

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I have a button with remote=>true that calls a popup (a jquery popup, not a real one) in the following way:

```
$modal = $('#modal')
$modal_close = $modal.find('.close')
$modal_container = $('#modal-container')
$task_select_div = $('.activity_task_add')

# Handle modal links with the data-remote attribute
$('a[data-remote]').on 'ajax:success',  (xhr, data, status) ->
  $modal
    .html(data)
    .prepend($modal_close)
    .css('top', $(window).scrollTop() + 150)
    .show()

#This is the callback that is not being executed.
$('form[data-remote]').on 'ajax:success',  (xhr, data, status) ->
  alert(data)
  $modal_container.hide()
  $modal.hide()
  $task_select_div.html(data)
```

In that popup I have another form with remote_tag in the submit button of this form I call and action that has the following code at the bottom:

```
respond_to do |format|
    if @task.save
       format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
       format.json { render json: @task, status: :created, location: @task }
       format.js {render :partial => 'tasks', :locals => {:tasks => current_user.department.tasks}}
    else
     format.html { render action: "new" }
     format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
end
```

It executes format.js and the console says "Rendered tasks/_tasks.html.erb (5.8ms)" but the callback for the ajax call is not working.

```
$('form[data-remote]').on 'ajax:success',  (xhr, data, status) ->
  alert(data)
```

I need to receive an ajax:success event in order to hide the Popup. 
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

Changed my respond_to do |format| for this:

```
if request.xhr?
  task_list = render_to_string :partial => 'tasks', :locals => {:tasks => current_user.department.tasks}
  task_list =  task_list.html_safe.gsub(/\n/, '').gsub(/\t/, '').gsub(/\r/, '')
  render :json => {:html => task_list, :error => ''}
else
  respond_to do |format|
    if @task.save
          format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render json: @task, status: :created, location: @task }  
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

And my javascript for this:

```
$('form[data-remote]').on 'ajax:success',  (xhr, data, status) ->
  $modal_container.hide()
  $modal.hide()
  $task_select_div.html(data.html)
```

What do you think of this solution? Any drawbacks?

Comment: FYI `.gsub(/[\n\t\r]/, '')` or `.gsub(/\n|\t|\r/, '')` are a couple of ways to avoid doing multiple gsubs.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line :

```
format.js {render :partial => 'tasks', :locals => {:tasks => current_user.department.tasks}}
```

Update your js callback :

```
$('form[data-remote]').on 'ajax:success',  (xhr, data, status) ->
  alert("hello world")
  $modal_container.hide()
  $modal.hide()
  $task_select_div.html(<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'tasks', :locals => {:tasks => current_user.department.tasks} ) %>)
```

Comment: How can I pass local variables? Is this a standard rails 3 way? 
Shouldn't I use the coffeescript files?

Comment: I've never tried to pass local variables, just instance variable. Can't you use instance variables ? Yes, it's pretty standard, you are not supposed to use coffescript files exclusively. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/ for more info

Comment: May be `format.js {:locals => {:tasks => current_user.department.tasks}` just works fine ?

Comment: Let me understand,,,,, My action gets executed and format.js just sets the locals.
After that the actions.js.erb gets executed. In what folder should I add action.js.erb?

Comment: Another thing, that action is executed both on its own page and on a Popup. Just the popup must make an ajax call, the other one shouldn't execute that javascript

Comment: yes. action.js.erb should be in the right view folder : app/views/controller as any other views of the controller.

Comment: Do I have to import that js or it is automatically added?

Comment: the file action.js.erb is just the callback of the ajax call (and in your case, it just opens a modal). Your partial "tasks" can be used with or without the ajax call in any view ( .html.erb or .js.erb)

Comment: No, only files in "assets" folder mus be imported. action.js.erb is like a view.

Comment: Sorry but that action is wrong. Let me explain again.
At first I make an ajax call to open a popup with a form. This ajax call works and I can open this popup. 
The popup contains a form with remote tag. When I press the submit button I call an action (create) and I need to refresh a partial within the parent view of the popup. So I have to close the popup and refresh the partial. I will update the code of my question because I didn't write the full code of my coffeescript. Sorry

Comment: If you want to do with ajax-success event, remove "format.js" line in the controller and display your partial with javascript.

Comment: Can you post your form code (the view with the form) ? Try to add an id to your form because `$('form[data-remote]')` does not seem to work

Comment: It works if I don't render a partial. If I change the format.js and respond with render :json => { :status=> 'OK'} it get executed.

Comment: I am trying to use the erb js. I got this message in the console Rendered tasks/create.js.erb (4.2ms) but the js is not being executed. Why?

Comment: I also added an alert as first sentence. The js is correctly rendered (viewing response on firebug) but it doesn't get executed.

Comment: It's possible there is a javascript error in your create.js.erb. Can you post the code ?

Comment: Just try to put an `alert("test")` (and nothing else) in your create.js.erb and tell me if it works.

Comment: It's normal firebug doesn't find any error (I already had the problem). Just put the alert and nothing else (everything commented)

Comment: I changed my js code to alert('hello') but it didn't worked either. Shouldn't it be called from the view in order to get executed?

I already solved the problem but I am curious about that. The js renders ok in the response, but I don't know how to execute it.

Comment: Please use one of the [chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) instead of comments for extended discussion.  Thanks.